# How to control number of columns after pivoting date as column

Tags: sql-server

Here is the sample query:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

Select @cols = COALESCE(@cols +',[' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReportedDate,120)+']',      '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), reportedDate, 120)
+']')       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),reportedDate,120)         AS reportedDate FROM Activity       ) PV ORDER BY reportedDate desc


SELECT @query = 'SELECT * FROM (    SELECT  b.Description, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), reportedDate, 120) as reportedDate,Status FROM Activity    left join ActivityType b     on b.activityTypeId = Activity.ActivityTypeId ) AS t PIVOT  (   COUNT(reportedDate)    FOR reportedDate IN( ' + @cols + ' )' + ') AS p ;'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

This is my sample image:
I want to control the date columns limit into only 8 columns.
as reference of what I mean please see the second table and its different from the first table.

So in my first table date column from '2020-01-07' up to '2019-11-12'
However my second table only up date '2020-01-07' up to '2019-11-19'

[image]
I want to get the result as shown in this second Table
assuming that this date '2020-01-07' is newly added.
so the '2019-11-12' will not be included.
[image]
I hope I did will explaining my point.

Comment: In lieu of screenshots, it's more helpful if you provide the `CREATE TABLE` statements and sample data the reproduce the screenshot. You can also share it in an online fiddle to help others answer your question more directly. Perhaps [start here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8245cb0fd08afd6821c43798f741912) and fill in the sample data to complete your example. See also: [repro], [ask]. Welcome to the network :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the inner query to following using `TOP ()` `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` to limit to 8 distinct date

```
SELECT  TOP (8) CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReportedDate, 120)  AS ReportedDate 
FROM    Activity       
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ReportedDate, 120)
ORDER BY ReportedDate
```

Comment: I have solve this problem, however how to use this pivot query in asp.net mvc to be display in Views? I got stack on this part any idea?